# Are there any research papers which show why Wasserstein distance is better than Jensen-Shannon/KL_div/Bhattacharya distance for specific use cases?

Tags: distributions, distance, metric, divergence, wasserstein

I am trying to find reliable research work which show why displacement based metrics such as Wasserstein distance is a better suited metric than Jensen-Shannon distance in specific use cases and for certain set of distributions.

Are there any well known works which delve into this ?

Comment: Aside from No Free Lunch theorems? What sort sort of "better" are you looking for, and more importantly why?